# How do I stop <li> elements from overlapping

Tags: html, css

[image]

When I resize the window (make it smaller), the "li" elements (class: "skill-list") will overlap each other. They will be displayed just fine when the window is in full screen, but when I make the window smaller, they will overlap each other. Not sure if it has to do something with text alignment or padding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background-color: #696969;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-image {
  height: 8rem;
  width: 8rem;
  border-radius: 20rem;
  border: 0.3rem solid white;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.profile-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.header-links {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.header-links a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.9rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.header-links a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.name-title {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;
}

.wallpaper {
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  background-color: azure;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.about {
  border-left: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-right: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

#projects {
  border-left: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-right: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.skill-list li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Zetta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82c7176f2a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <figure class="name-title">
          <img class="profile-image" src="https://gamerheadquarters.com/hub/avatar/fallout76tshirt.jpg" alt="profile photo">
          <figcaption>
            <h1>John Johnson</h1>
            <h2>Front End Developer</h2>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="header-links">
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
          <a href="contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>

  <section>
    <img class="wallpaper" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/691668/pexels-photo-691668.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="mountains">
  </section>

  <section>
    <main>
      <div class="align-center">
        <h1 id="about" class="about">About</h1>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Maecenas
        tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum
        sodales, augue velit cursus nunc</p>
      <div class="align-center">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <ul class="skill-list">
          <li>HTML & CSS</li>
          <li>Javascript</li>
          <li>React</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="margin-top">
      <div class="align-center">
        <h1 id="projects" class="projects">Projects</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `display` from `inline` to `inline-block` in `.skill-list li`

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I just posted a screenshot. You can see that "HTML & CSS" goes on top when the window gets smaller.

Answer (score 1):

use flex for this kind of placement

```css
li{
display:inline;

}
ul{

text-align:center;
}



body{
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
  background-color: #696969;
  padding-top: 2rem; 
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-image{
  height: 8rem;
  width: 8rem;
  border-radius: 20rem;
  border: 0.3rem solid white;
  transition: transform 1s;
  
}

.profile-image:hover{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.header-links{
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.header-links a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.9rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.header-links a:hover{
  color: orange;
}

.name-title{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;
}

.wallpaper{
  width: 100%;
}

main{
  background-color: azure;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.about{
  border-left: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-right: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  display: inline; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

#projects{
  border-left: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-right: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  display: inline; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.margin-top{
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.align-center{
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}

.skill-list li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 4rem;
}
html css
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Zetta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82c7176f2a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li>HTML & CSS</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
<li>React</li>
</ul>
</div>
  <section>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
          <figure class="name-title">
            <img class="profile-image" src="https://gamerheadquarters.com/hub/avatar/fallout76tshirt.jpg" alt="profile photo">
              <figcaption>  
                <h1>John Johnson</h1>
                <h2>Front End Developer</h2>
              </figcaption>
          </figure>
        <div class="header-links">
          <a  href="#about">About</a>
          <a  href="#projects">Projects</a>
          <a  href="contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </section>
    
    <section>
      <img class="wallpaper" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/691668/pexels-photo-691668.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="mountains">
    </section>

  <section>
    <main>
      <div class="align-center">
        <h1 id="about" class="about">About</h1>
      </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
          Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
          Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. 
          Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
          imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
          Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing 
          Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
          Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc</p> 
      
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <div class="align-center">
         
            <div>HTML & CSS</div>
            <div>Javascript</div>
            <div>React</div>
          
      </div>
  
  
  
      <div class="margin-top">
      <div class="align-center"> 
        <h1 id="projects" class="projects">Projects</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works, but is there a way to use ul and li tags instead of div?

Comment: i updated the snippet.  look at the very top section

Comment: the problem with the li's is now you have to think about left and right margins for spacing and still keep the line of text centered. doable, but flex is just easier

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
.skill-list li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 4rem;
}
```

use

```
.skill-list li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4rem;
}
```

so when you'll resize the window, it will stack each element in a new row.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I just posted a screenshot. You can see that "HTML & CSS" goes on top when the window gets smaller